# sklearn Multiclass Classifier number of predicted classes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on a multi-class classification problem, where I need to get a pre-defined number of classes in the prediction set. In the code below, I'm using sklearn's OnveVsRestClassifier for Logistic Regression

```
classifier = Pipeline([
        ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

The code above works fine, and it returns a variable number of classes for each test case. I was wondering how can I specify it return N number of predicted classes for each test set.

Comment: Aren't *all* classification problems "multi-class"? ;)

Comment: I tried to use the same terminology as sklearn does : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html . In simpler terms, each training and test set have more than one classes they correspond to.

Comment: If each sample in your dataset may be in one or more classes at the same time - it's called **multilabel** classification problem, read more about it from link that you provided. I haven't seen your dataset, but as your link describes - OneVsRestClassifier already supports Multi label classification, so maybe you just need to convert your y matrix to indicator format with MultiLabelBinarizer.

Comment: Provide examples of your expected output, because as you describe it now, it seems what you need is not provided part of the API. Meaning you'll need to divide the data yourself to get that output.